# Checking for missing account numbers from one of the tables

Tags: sql

I'm missing acccount numbers from t01 table that are in q04 table.

How do I display the missing account numbers. I only want batch number 270864 from the T01 and importid 680 from q04

t01 table data

```
account numbet1 2 3 7 8

Batch numbers 270864
```

q04 table data

```
account numbers 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 

ImpoortID 680
```

Here is the code I'm trying to use with no results;

```
SELECT *
FROM [DS_PROD].[dbo].[T01_TransactionMaster] t01
WHERE  t01.BatchNumber = '270864' AND t01.AccountNumber 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [DS_PROD].[dbo].[Q04_ImportDetails] q04                                           
            WHERE q04.ImportId = 680)
```

Comment: how do I get all columns to display from both tables.  It shows q04 table not the t01 columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause is off. You should be doing `t01.AccountNumber NOT IN` instead of NOT EXISTS.

Also based on the data you provided, you should be querying table Q04 for which AccountNumbers are NOT IN table T01. Not the other way around. All the AccountNumbers in T01 are in Q04 (1, 2, 3, 7, 8). You want a query to return (4, 5, 6)

```
SELECT *
FROM [DS_PROD].[dbo].[Q04_ImportDetails] q04
WHERE Q04.ImportId = 680 AND q04.AccountNumber NOT IN 
    (SELECT AccountNumber 
    FROM [DS_PROD].[dbo].[T01_TransactionMaster] t01 
    WHERE t01.BatchNumber = '270864')
```

Comment: how do I get all columns to display from both tables. It shows q04 table not the t01 columns – user1667160 just now edit

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
SELECT *
FROM [DS_PROD].[dbo].[T01_TransactionMaster] t01
WHERE  t01.BatchNumber = '270864' AND t01.AccountNumber 
NOT EXISTS (SELECT **ACCNTNUMBER** FROM [DS_PROD].[dbo].[Q04_ImportDetails]      q04                                           
        WHERE q04.ImportId = 680)
```